# How to avoid sql strings using linq (WPF project)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq, mvvm

I'm developing an application using Microsoft WPF on top of SQL Server for one piece of a larger system.

This is a college senior project, and I would like things to be as "best practices" as possible for portfolio reasons. I understand that MVVM is the way to go to structure the WPF application itself.

Furthermore, I am interested in taking advantage of LINQ instead of the "SQL query string" method of data manipulation and retrieval, however I am fairly frustrated as I can't seem to get a straight answer on how to do this the right way (or if this is even best practices).

I found a promising tutorial, however it calls on using Linq-to-SQL to create the object relations which I have read as being deprecated, and isn't available in VS2017. I found a dated tutorial that was using ADO.NET for this (~2010) however it was giving me issues.

Should I stick to the "SQL query string" way of doing things?

Comment: I suggest using [entity framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using Entity Framework in c#.

1. Add the Entity Model of your database into your application.
2. then create an object in the class that you want to invoke data

   ```
   <your-entities> context = new <your-entities>();
   ```
3. then you can invoke data using linq

   ```
   var select = from a in context.<table-name>.IEnumerable() select a;
   ```

   finally you can read data using `select` variable.

eg-:

```
 foreach(var item in select){

 }
```

Comment: Entity model seems to be the best way, the repository pattern seems to be fantastic too but I don't have the time.

Answer (score 2):

Best practices? DON'T use LINQ to SQL. I am not against the idea of something that simplifies things for small student projects, but while it simplifies things, it makes provides a nightmare for DBAs in the real world. Entity Framework can also cause this heartburn, but there are ways around it.

If by "SQL query string" way of doing things as coding SQL query strings and sending to the database from your code. That can work, if things are predictable. But, if you are too dynamic, you just repeat the DBA nightmare.

I would look up repository patterns and learn how to create a repository. While you might not have to do this always in the real world, it is great exercise in learning abstraction. For items where you might need to work on a lot of joins, consider examining the creation of views and build a few stored procedures. All of these will serve you when you leave the classroom for business.

As a bit of trivia, LINQ to SQL was an experiment written on top of reactive extensions (Eric Maier when he was with Microsoft and not bashing Agile). It might not have ever been released had it not been for SQL Server being delayed from a co-launch with Visual Studio 2008. The delay of SQL Server meant the delay of Entity Framework, which meant the "build a site in 15 minutes" talk was FUBARed. Thus, LINQ to SQL became a de facto "standard" and DBAs everywhere started carrying guns to work (okay, the last part is not true, but the rest is).

Comment: Fantastic, the repository pattern looks very useful, and some of the work could definitely be done with views and stored procedures.